# Mudar conteúdo ao clicar em ícone e mudar o ícone

Tags: javascript

Tenho a seguinte situação: duas divs que são exibidas clicando em ícones. Cada tela tem um ícone e um conteúdo específico, seria um toggle, mas do conteúdo e do ícone. Deixei anexo uma imagem do que seria e aqui uma ideia do que seria a mudança do ícone: http://jsfiddle.net/xdC29/[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pelo seu jsfiddle vejo que usa [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/).

Faça assim:

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle fa-plus-circle');
  $('.content').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.content.active {
  display:block;
}
.content {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Click me! <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
<div class="content active">
   + div plus
</div>
<div class="content">
   - div minus
</div>
```

[exemplo JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4jansgeL/9/)

Comment: A troca do ícone está ok, eu precisaria que além de trocar o ícone exibisse duas divs com conteúdos diferentes. Digamos quando escolho o ícone "mais" apareça um conteúdo específico para ela. E quando for o "menos" que seja outro conteúdo.

Comment: Vou fazer isso. Aguarde um pouco